# Modding popcorn popper: shut off heater while keeping fan on

Tags: switches, solid-state-relay, heater

So, I'm trying the age-old tactic of roasting coffee with a popcorn popper, and while it works, I would like to have better control over the heat applied in order to prolong the roasting. I've seen other mods to popcorn poppers, but the schematics for this one are bugging me.

I've got a bifinett 1200w popcorn popper, and to the best of my ability, this schematic represents how the internals are wired (I'm not an electrical engineer so I might be wrong). Note: I'm missing a capacitor connecting the two AC wires.

[image: Text]

This is an image of the "Fancy Bridge Rectifier", **which connects to a motor working as a fan**:
[image: Text]

And this is a picture of the heating element, with the labeled HL, HT, and HR points:
[image: Text]

I would like to accomplish two things, both related to controlling the heat while leaving the fan always runnning:

1. Add a switch to, at least, the main coil, so that I can control the heat. This would be my main objective. However, from the schematic, I don't see how I can turn off the main coil without turning off also the fan and secondary coil. Plus, it seems to me that the main coil lowers the voltage that is passed on to the rectifier and secondary coil, so I don't see how to go around it.
2. Later I would like to control the main heating element with a solid-state relay so that I can control the temperature through an ESP8266 I have that is measuring temperature with a thermocouple positioned inside the heating chamber. This one I have no clue how to wire up, but this is also more for "future work", right now I want to accomplish 1) first.

Comment: I don't see the fan you are worried about interrupting if you switched the main coil. Also, since a bridge rectifier has 4 wires total (two input and two output), I don't think your schematic is complete enough for anyone to help. I'm not on this forum everyday so I can't say when I'll be able to comment again, but I think others could better assist you with a more complete diagram.

Comment: Hello. What I call a "fancy bridge rectifier"  is actually a board that I believe converts AC to DC, and which is then connected to a fan, as I've pointed out in my question. The second image shows said board. As for the number of wires I'm not sure, you can see on the second image there are only two entries into that board. I'm not sure how it works, but I believe it does have the 4 diodes of a bridge rectifier, so I'm guessing the other two terminals you mention connect to the motor.

Comment: Your "fancy bridge rectifier" seems to have 2 wires attached at the corner labelled 'N'. is One the Neutral wire and the other the 'HL' to the secondary coil?

Comment: @brhans Yes that is exactly it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This popcorn popper uses essentially the same circuit as many hair dryers- the elements form a dropping resistor for the DC fan, so you can't turn the heater off without affecting the fan. Image from [here](http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Electrical_Equipment_Circuit/POKO_TD_169C_Hair_dryer_circuit_diagram.html).  Ignore VD and the switch, that's for the "low" position.

[image]

What you could do is provide a separate DC supply for the fan motor and disconnect it from the bridge rectifier assembly. To avoid affecting the remaining circuit you could replace the fan with an equivalent resistor (that may not be necessary but it's safer since the short element may otherwise get too hot).

To do this you need to figure out the fan voltage and current rating. It may be marked on the motor, but if not you could (carefully) measure it.

For switching the remaining elements you could use a relay or an SSR. It's a trade-off the relay will have limited life (but for a coffee roaster maybe that's not a big deal), and the SSR will require a big heatsink and/or a fan of its own. You could also use a relay and a resistor to switch a triac which is pretty much the same as an SSR. It wouldn't hurt to add another thermal safety fuse, especially if you're depending on firmware to turn the fan on whenever the heater is on.

The unit will have been designed, tested and certified not to cause an unsafe situation if the fan motor fails, but you're increasing the chances of that if you use firmware, and making other modifications so extreme care is called for. The current arrangement ensures the fan is always powered whenever the heater is on.

Edit: DPDT selection (CAUTION, this requires one side of low voltage supply to be tied to the mains). It would also be possible to use a somewhat higher (like 1.5V more) voltage and switch the input to the bridge rectifier), but I have a suspicion the fan motor voltage will turn out to be something convenient like 12V at 5-10W.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fykDv6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought, but I was hoping to avoid using a separate transformer for the fan. Could I add a switch just for the secondary coil? I'm not sure how much difference it would make in terms of heat control as it's the smaller coil, but maybe it could slow the process down a bit? And yes, my intention is to have the fan always running when the machine is on to avoid overheating problems.

Comment: Both parts of the heater have to be 'on' to power the fan with the present circuit. It's basically a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) with the rectifier/fan load in parallel with one of the resistors.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany What does [this character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrQuc.png) mean? It seems based off of big (man with outstretched arms) or large. But I'm just a neophyte in Chinese and I'd enjoy knowing. Thanks.

Comment: @jonk alone 头 (tou2) means head. Like 头发 (tou2 fa3) is hair (human hair on  your head- arm hair etc. is a different character- more like fur). Together, 电源插头 (dian4 yuan2 cha1 tou2) means electrical power plug. 电 is electricity. The traditional characters for 头 and 电 were 頭 and 電. In the latter you can see a picture of lightning striking under the rain (雨). The former is supposed to be a picture of a man's head (right hand side) and the left is a hint as to the sound (sound + meaning).

Comment: P.S. Wikipedia has some of the evolution of the 頁 radical [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_181) where it once had a bit of a resemblance to a head. The whole character 头 or 頭 is also used as a 'counting word' for things like livestock, where it actually corresponds to English for once (we say "head of cattle").

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Thanks so much for this. It's sincerely appreciated. I'm ignoring the spoken parts, as there are too many dialects and I will never have the time. So I'm stuck just with the written; and you've already hinted at some subtle aspects that relate to spoken connections that I will forever miss out on, I guess. Thanks....

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Simplified vs Traditional is still a struggle for me. I received lessons from Chinese from Taipai, years back. So that's where my beginning originates. Newspapers from Taiwan. It was such a pleasure... those moments.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany so, in sum, what parts would I need once I knew the voltage across the fan? Let's say it was a 24v fan. How would the new schematic look like with a transformer for the fans and a switch/ssr for the heaters? And what type of resistance would I need to put in the rectifiers place?

Comment: The current draw also needs to be known. You could use a DC supply (if one is available that fits the requirements) or a transformer. These days a power supply may be more sensible than a transformer. Then you need two switches of some kind to control the fan and heater individually. That could be a module.

Comment: Can I connect a power supply directly to the terminals of the fan, and have a 2-way switch that toggles between off/normal functioning of the popper/just the power supply powering the fan, or would the power supply back propagate current/cause some problem?

Comment: Or... a 3PDT on-off-on switch that alternates between the power supply and the bridge rectifier, with the bridge rectifier side also controlling the switch that now turns on the system.

Comment: A 3PDT is the minimum if you want to switch a dummy load and keep the DC supply isolated from the mains. If it's acceptable to have the DC supply output tied to the mains, a DPDT is sufficient. Seems like a needless complication to retain that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. I don't see how I could do it with a dpdt even when sharing mains between both circuits, but if you could add a schematic of that to your response (either 3PDT or DPDT) that would be excellent, and I would mark it as an accepted answer. But in any case, if you don't want to go to the trouble I'll just make a self-answer with a 3PDT and I'll reference your answer for the idea of a separate power supply.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I'm revisiting this now, to try to actually implement it. I was wondering, what is the purpose of the R3 dummy resistance? Wouldn't that be necessary only if the heater was still on when using the power supply? And how is the heater being turned off with this solution, when switching over to the power supply?

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe use a capacitive dropper to power the fan rectifier. picking the right part here is impossible without knowing what current and voltage the fan needs,